# Matrix multiplication with vectorization in c++ executes for a long time

Tags: c++, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have several matrices that I want to multiply in c++ with allowing vectorization. However the following code results in a large execution time  ~858146125 ns. How do I modify the code so I have vectorization of the matrix multiplication and reach around 100ns of execution time.
I am using the flag O3.

```
   const int ROWS = 1000;
    const int COLS = 1000;
    const int ROWS1 = 1000;
    const int COLS1 = 1000;
    const int l = 1000;
    double random_matrix[ROWS][COLS];
    double random_matrix1[ROWS1][COLS1];

    double mult[l][l];
    int i;
    int j;
    /* generate number: */
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            random_matrix[i][j] = i + j;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS1; j++)
            random_matrix1[i][j] = i + j;
    }

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (size_t row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
        for (size_t tmp = 0; tmp < COLS1; ++tmp) {
            mult[row][tmp] = random_matrix[row][0]*random_matrix1[0][tmp];
            for (size_t col = 1; col < COLS; ++col) {
                mult[row][tmp] += random_matrix[row][col] * random_matrix1[col][tmp];
            }
        }
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Elapsed time in nanoseconds : "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count()
              << " ns" << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n";
    for (i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<COLS1;j++)
            std::cout << mult[i][j] <<std::endl; //display table
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
```

Comment: According to [latency numbers every programmer should know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832), one access to main memory is 100 ns. Your budget has already been blown several times before you even computed _one_ element of the final array. Where did you get this target from?

Comment: A more useful comment, then: if you transpose the second matrix you're walking both arrays row-wise. This will significantly improve your memory cache hit rate and give the compiler an easier time in spotting the vectorization opportunity.

Comment: In the paper "The case for Learned Index Structures" [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01208.pdf) on page 10 you can see that they reach a multiplication and addition of matrices in less than 100ns.

Comment: Where on that page does it state that? The table mentions the lookup time of a single value.

Comment: Figure 4: Learned Index vs B-Tree, they say that the lookup time is in ns . Previously they mention that they extract the weights and the bias from a neural network in tensorflow and they perform multiplication of matrices in c++ in order to reach this result

Comment: Do you really need `double`. In your code, your data is all integers (`i + j`). Changing that might has a massive effect on performance. Also, are you compiling in 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: Yes I need double, the general idea is that once I extract the weights from a neural network for an input lets say A=[1,1] I will multiply it with the weights and add the baises as they did. Since the weights are double I need double/float.  Also @Botje the lookup time is for one input which is multiplied by the weigths of the neural network which can be large matrices

Comment: @AnaSmile Section 3.7.1 explains the table. The "model(ns)" column is the average time spent evaluating the neural network for a given key, and "lookup(ns)" is the average time to look up a value. They do not reveal the size of the network evaluated, but on the worst case it is two layers of 16 nodes each, so 2 times 16x16 matrix multiplication. That is quite a few orders of magnitude less than the 1000x1000 you are trying to do!

Comment: @Botje their actual size of the matrix is 32 nodes with two layers. But still they mention that the simplest model which is just a linear regression is executed in 30 ns, which I also cannot reach with the same code mentioned above.  Even when I have smaller matrices the execution time is much larger than 2000ns. They mention that they provide SIMD auto-vectorization, but the same does not imply for my code, therefore I need help in that sense. For  multiplying a matrix [1,32], [32,32] I need around 3000ns

Comment: As I and other people have pointed out: transposing the second matrix should give a good speed boost. Make sure to use the right flags so the compiler vectorizes.

Comment: But wouldn't the transpose operation take more time?

Comment: Yes, but you would only do it once, while you would evaluate the model millions of times.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the input and the discussion. :)

Comment: Small benchmark with clang8.0 as an example: if you access mult, random_matrix and random_matrix1 row-wise, you get up to 30x better performance then if you access the 3 of them col-wise.

Comment: And with gcc9.1 on my machine: access of the three matrices col-wise: 3.6e7ns, access of the three matrices row-wise: 3.4e6ns (10 times faster).

Comment: @MFnx Could you maybe provide a pseudocode of the multiplication of the matrices with row-wise access

Comment: @AnaSmile In your line mult[row][tmp] += random_matrix[row][col] * random_matrix1[col][tmp], all the matrices are accessed row-wise, except for matrix1. There you loose speed. Check on how an array double[ROW][COL] is constructed, and you'll understand why it goes faster to access them row-wise. Here is a small benchmark. http://quick-bench.com/n9YRvK1wuQluCENJ3GeJ-_upsMs

Comment: @MFnx how should I access all of the row wise ? should I transpose the matrix as previously mentioned?

Comment: @AnaSmile That would be an option. Or maybe construct it already transposed. Depends on your program. Check out Eigen, you'll love it.

Comment: @MFnx Eigen is too slow for this computation. I am trying to vectorize the code, in order to reach around 200 ns for [32,32][32,32] multiplication

Comment: @AnaSmile With all due respect, if you manage to do it faster than Eigen, I'll hire you. If Eigen is slower than your implementation, than you are using Eigen wrong.

Comment: @MFnx currently I am trying different methods for multiplying matrices [10,10] X [10,10] and here is the time I get:
Matrices as one dimensional arrays method: 297 ns;
Normal matrix multiplication: 578 ns;
The above mentioned: 471ns;
The same but transposed : 450 ns;
Eigen: 4000 ns.

Could you maybe provide an example where Eigen performs better, maybe I am not using the right flags. Currently I use O3

Comment: @AnaSmile I see you use arrays on the stack. With eigen, do you use matrices on the stack? Or do you use MatrixXd?

Comment: @MFnx I am using MatrixXf

Comment: @AnaSmile That's a matrix allocated on the heap. Not the same.

Comment: Anyways, those matrices are a bit large to be on the stack ;). I'll see if I can get you an example of speed, later on today.

Comment: MatrixXf mat= MatrixXf::Random(10,10);
MatrixXf mat1= MatrixXf::Random(10,10);
mat* mat1
@MFnx
Could you maybe tell me how to modify it so I can reach the performance you are speaking about? Thank you

Comment: This should be moved to a chat or you should post a new answer. We shouldn't be discussing this here.

Comment: @MFnx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461326/efficient-matrix-multiplication-in-c-ideally-with-vectorization just posted a new question so you can maybe provide the answer there

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you'll never get to 100 ns total execution time with these matrix sizes, with vectorization or without. Matrix multiplication of two matrices 1000 x 1000 elements takes on the order of 1000 ^ 3 = 1,000,000,000 multiply-adds. That is one billion operations.

Secondly, if performance matters so much to you, you should NOT write your own code for these low-level mathematical primitives. There are optimized C++ libraries that will perform these operations for you, such as Eigen or BLAS (Intel MKL is a package that implements BLAS).

By using one of these packages, you not only get much better performance, but also avoid the potential pitfalls or bugs that you would likely have otherwise.

Comment: But if the code is vectorized, shouldn't this multiply-adds be minimized? Additionally I pointed to a paper in the comment of my question that claims to have reached this result.

Comment: @AnaSmile: vectorization will speed things up by maybe 4-8x, as far as I understand. Still, no need to do try to do it yourself, this will be amateur hour compared to what these specialized libraries do (the routines in there are vectorized). Regarding that paper - I don't know what those guys do, but all practical algorithms for dense matrix multiplication are O(N^3). You'll need one billion operations for those matrix sizes. Maybe their matrix sizes are tiny, I don't know, or maybe they don't have dense matrices.